# How to find if a string contain certain characters without considering sequence?

Tags: r, string

I'm trying to match a name using elements from another vector with R. But I don't know how to escape sequence when using `grep()` in R.

```
name <- "Cry River"
string <- c("Yesterday Once More","Are You happy","Cry Me A River")
grep(name, string, value = TRUE)
```

I expect the output to be "Cry Me A River", but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.*` in the pattern

```
grep("Cry.*River", string, value = TRUE)
#[1] "Cry Me A River"
```

Or if you are getting `names` as it is and can't change it, you can split on whitespace and insert the `.*` between the words like

```
grep(paste(strsplit(name, "\\s+")[[1]], collapse = ".*"), string, value = TRUE)
```

where the regex is constructed in the below fashion

```
strsplit(name, "\\s+")[[1]]
#[1] "Cry"   "River"

paste(strsplit(name, "\\s+")[[1]], collapse = ".*")
#[1] "Cry.*River"
```

Comment: Thank you! Also, what if the "string" above is actually a column in a dataframe, do I have to transform it first?

Comment: @staifmis108 No need. You can use `df$column_name` instead of `string` where `df` is the name of your dataframe and `column_name` name of your column.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option, using `grepl`:

```
name <- "Cry River"
parts <- paste0("\\b", strsplit(name, "\\s+")[[1]], "\\b")
string <- c("Yesterday Once More","Are You happy","Cry Me A River")
result <- sapply(parts, function(x) { grepl(x, string) })
string[rowSums(result) == length(parts)]

[1] "Cry Me A River"
```

The strategy here is to first split the string containing the various search terms, and generating individual regex patterns for each term.  In this case, we generate:

```
\bCry\b and \bRiver\b
```

Then, we iterate over each term, and using `grepl` we check that the term appears in each of the strings.  Finally, we retain only those matches which contained all terms.

Answer (score 0):

We can do the `grepl` on splitted string and `Reduce` the `list` of logical `vector`s to a single `logical`vector` and extract the matching element in 'string'

```
string[Reduce(`&`, lapply(strsplit(name, " ")[[1]], grepl, string))]
#[1] "Cry Me A River"
```

---

Also, instead of `strsplit`, we can insert the `.*` with `sub`

```
grep(sub(" ", ".*", name), string, value = TRUE)
#[1] "Cry Me A River"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using stringr.  Is order important? Is case important? Is it important to match whole words.  If you would just like to match 'Cry' and 'River' in any order and don't care about case.

```
name <- "Cry River"
string <- c("Yesterday Once More",
"Are You happy",
"Cry Me A River", 
"Take me to the River or I'll Cry", 
"The Cryogenic River Rag",
"Crying on the Riverside")

string[str_detect(string, pattern = regex('\\bcry\\b', ignore_case = TRUE)) & 
             str_detect(string, regex('\\bRiver\\b', ignore_case = TRUE))]
```